# MIMO power output

Tags: antenna, wifi, digital-communications

If local regulations require Wifi's EIRP to be less than 200mW, then for a 4 channel MIMO antenna Wifi tranceiver, will each channel limit the power output to 50mW and each have a 50mW power amplifier? How is MIMO tranceiver regulated by EIRP requirements?

Answer (score 1):

It depends a bit on the actual size of your transmitter system (technically, your MIMO antennas could also be 10 km apart), but for Wifi, you'd need to understand the whole transmitting *system* as *one system*, and hence, EIRP applies to the sum waveform in any direction.

Comment: (1) To get the same EIRP, will MIMO Wifi use smaller power amplifiers? (2) If EIRP applies to any direction, considering the "peak directions" where all wave sum up, then the transmitter should only output very low power just for those directions to be compliant, this is why the question was asked.

Comment: These are new questions, and you should be asking them as such (instead of in the comments). but yes, what you describe is the whole point of restricting EIRP, so I'm confused where your confusion stems from.